# SELECT DISTINCT with two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by, distinct

I need to distinct both `SenderId`, and `RecipientId`.

So I did this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT M.SenderId, R.StudentId as RecipientId
FROM Message M (nolock) INNER JOIN Recipient R (nolock) ON M.Id=R.MessageId 
GROUP BY M.SenderId, R.StudentId
HAVING StudentId=1 OR SenderId=1
```

And this works, but I also need the M.Text field there, but without the **distinct**.
So I added this:

```
GROUP BY M.SenderId, R.StudentId, M.Text
```

But this does not work.

Comment: Could there be more than one M.Text for each distinct M.Sender, R.StudentId?   If so which one would you want to select?

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag because of the `(nolock)` keyword

Comment: Using `distinct` **and** `group by` does not make sense

Comment: You don't need both the `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`.  You also could use a `WHERE` instead of the `HAVING`.

Comment: @djikay You don't need to select a column to be able to use it in the group by

Comment: ...but it IS good practice!

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  Your explanation does not clarify what you really want.

Comment: RE: using a column in select to use in group by (Lamak / Strawberry) confirmed you don't need to, debate that it's "good practice", however would argue you would want to - i.e. generally if you're grouping by things you'd want to see which of these groups each result row related to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some options; not sure from the wording which best suits your requirements, but suspect one will...

```
--selects unique combination of sender, recipient and text
--meaning the combo of 3 is unique, but within that combo values
--in each individual column may be repeated

SELECT DISTINCT M.SenderId
, R.StudentId as RecipientId
, M.Text
FROM Message M (nolock) 
INNER JOIN Recipient R (nolock) ON R.MessageId = M.Id
where StudentId=1 
or SenderId=1
```

or

```
--returns all unique combos of SenderId and RecipientId
--along with a single corresponding Text field
--max() is just an arbitrary aggregate function to ensure we only
--get 1 result for M.Text

SELECT M.SenderId
, R.StudentId as RecipientId
, max(M.Text)
FROM Message M (nolock) 
INNER JOIN Recipient R (nolock) ON R.MessageId = M.Id
where StudentId=1 
or SenderId=1
group bu M.SenderId
, R.StudentId
```

Comment: This does not work since the "max(M.Text)" gets the Text where the length is bigger than the others that is related to those two ids instead of the Text relative to the most recent row

Comment: @FelipeSkinner; it works depending on what the requirement is.  You're referring to the second SQL.  For each distinct sender/recipient combination it will return a single arbitrary (max) message.text value from those associated with that combination of sender/recipient.

Comment: @FelipeSkinner regarding your comment on length; there's no logic for that - max applied to a string (varchar, etc) value gives the last value when sorted alphabetically (i.e. given 'AAA', 'B' it would return 'B'; given 'AAA', 'A' it would return 'AAA').

Comment: Maybe it was because I tested with "car" and "hello" so I assumed that. It was my bad since I assumed the Text was not arbitrary but the most recent one

Comment: There's another catch there because it could return something like "{1,2}, {2,3}, {2,4}, {3,2}" and those two pairs {2,3} - {3,2} are the same... Any idea how we could solve that? I'm working my way around it with multiple queries but I'd like to know if there's any other way

Comment: @FelipeSkinner in the above case {2,3} and {3,2} are different, because they refer to the sender and the recipient; i.e. different entities.  If instead these were both, say, messageParticipants, you could account for it using something like the following: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/20409 - however that would be a different question to the above, so should be asked as a new question on here.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question properly, this will group what you want and distinct SenderId, and StudentId:

```
SELECT M.SenderId, R.StudentId as RecipientId, M.Text
FROM Message M (nolock) INNER JOIN Recipient R (nolock) ON M.Id=R.MessageId 
GROUP BY M.SenderId, R.StudentId, M.Text
HAVING COUNT(StudentId) = 1 OR COUNT(SenderId) = 1
```